# How to access Hudson CI from a mobile device like the iPhone or iPad?

Tags: iphone, continuous-integration, hudson, ipod

I really like Hudson CI and I do think it is the most useful and effective piece of software ever made for the Agile Application Lifecycle :-)

Anyway if the CI become unstable, the development is going to be really compromised, so keeping an eye on it is CRUCIAL !

Does anybody know about an effective solution for always monitoring it while you are "on the road" ? (maybe using your iPhone or iPod)

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen:
http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/HudsonMobi%252C+the+iPhone+client+for+Hudson+CI+monitoring
It provides a lot of views and features.

Answer (score 2):

Hudson has an [iPhone view plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/iPhoneView+Plugin) to format the Hudson web pages in a much more friendly format.

As well as email as suggested by @harschware, you could also use the Hudson [Jabber plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Jabber+Plugin) to send instant messages to your mobile device.

Comment: (+1) nice additional features, esp iPhone plugin...  (I notice that it's really new)

Comment: Nice ! ... but I was looking for something more "dynamic" than just a iPhone friendly web page rendering.

Comment: I tried to use the iPhone view plugin, but it does not render well on my iPod. Fonts are too small and I cannot use the links.

Is anybody using it ? Are you experiencing the same problems ?

Comment: The plugin works fine for me on an iPhone 3GS, with the latest iPhone OS.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check status configure it to email you when there is build failures.  As for being able to view the dashboard via a browser, iPhone/iPad have web browsers.

Comment: iPad is good enough but iPhone has a too small screen for that.
Moreover the e-mail is too generic and I receive an average of 150 mails/day ... do not want to receive new ones !